# Contantes no codeigniter com dados do DB

Tags: codeigniter, constantes

Boa tarde preciso pegar algumas configurações para o meu site que vem de uma tabela no banco de dados, atualmente utilizo variável mais dai toda hora tem que ficar indo lá no banco pra pegar, acho que isso pode deixar minha aplicação lenta não pode?

Caso verdadeiro qual seria a forma mais adequada?

Em busca no pai google vi que as constantes podem guardar dados pelo tempo que a aplicação ficar em execução, seria um boa pratica eu usar as constantes para deixar guardados os dados.

Os dados que preciso deixar gravado são, tenho um preço dos meus produtos, neles tenho que atribuir um desconto para pagamento a vista, mais quero deixar a opção para o meu cliente mudar essa taxa de desconto no admin dele, pra ele não ficar me pedindo depois de um tempo para ficar mudando ou vai saber tem clientes quer mudar toda mês.

Em uma busca na pasta config tem um arquivo constants.php, que se eu criar lá ele já fica para o site todo mais lá eu não consegui fazer load de um model acho que não deve ser possível fazer isso. Mais também não sei se será o correto utilizar constantes, preciso da ajuda de vcs. desde de já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não use constantes para valores dinâmicos.

Estas regras de descontos deverão ser definidos dentro de uma tabela do banco de dados, assim como você está fazendo agora. Eventualmente até uma tela para o usuário definir os valores de desconto.

A informação é pequena e não irá prejudicar a performance de sua aplicação.

Comment: obrigado lucas.